# Javascript replace two consecutive tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React app and I'm having the following issue:
My text editor fails at some html syntaxes. The package isn't very good itself so yeah.

What I am trying to achieve is transform the following syntax
`<p><p> hey </p></p>` into `<p> hey </p>`

I tried to do something like `text.replace(/<p><p>/g, '<p>')` but it is not a valid syntax.

Comment: Why isn't it a valid syntax? Seems correct to me and I don't get an error when using it.

Comment: Maybe you have to escape the <>? `text.replace(/\<p\>\<p\>/g, '<p>')`.

Comment: @AlexanderElert why? `<` and `>` don't have a special meaning in that regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const str = '<p><p> hey </p></p>'

const result = str.replace(/<p><p>/g, '<p>').replace(/<\/p><\/p>/g, '</p>')

console.log(result)
```

Or with a single regex:

```js
const str = '<p><p> hey </p></p>'

const result = /.*(<p>.*?<\/p>).*/g.exec(str)[1]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: The second one changes `<p>hello</p>` into simply `hello`

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what happened. It didn't work for me. lol.

Comment: Thanks VLAZ, corrected regex to keep `<p>hello</p>`